# How pass literal to overloaded operator

Tags: c++, qt

I have overloaded operator for my special type of logging in application:

```
CLogger * operator<<(CLogger *logger, QString &str)
{
    if(logger != nullptr)
    {
        logger->getStream()->operator <<( str);
        return logger;
    }
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

And then I'm trying to pass parameter through this operator in this way:

```
&myLog  << "Hello";
```

Where `myLog` is inscance of my `CLogger` class. I'm getting this error:

```
invalid operands of types 'CLogger*' and 'const char [6]' to binary 'operator<<'
     &myLog  << "Hello";
                ^
```

But if I'm passing `QString` object as this way everything is good:

```
QString hi = "Hello";
&myLog  << hi;
```

**How can I pass this string literal directly?**

Comment: Why are you taking a `CLogger *` instead of a `CLogger &`?

Comment: Because I need to define my logging level for example: `&myLog << LgLevel::Info << "Hello";` and when globally declared log level is lower than level of `LgLevel::Info` I need to return nullpointer and then nothing is saved in file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is your operator takes a `QString &str`, which is a lvalue reference.  A lvalue reference requires that you pass to it a lvalue (named object).  So in

```
&myLog  << "Hello";
```

`"Hello"` is not a named `Qstring` so you cannot bind to it.  What you want to do is take a `const QString &str`.  A `const&` can bind to a temporary which allows `"Hello"` to be converted to a temporary `Qsting` and then you can bind to that temporary.

Another option would be to overload the operator for a `const char*` which requires no conversion and lets you work with the string literal directly.  This can be advantageous as it can save you from the dynamic memory allocation that `Qstring` might do.

---

Another issue is that you should really take in the `CLogger` instance by reference.  Taking it by pointer stops you from overloading the operator for built in types since a pointer is a built in type and you cannot overload its operators.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I thought about passing parameter through `const char*`, but when I have changed my declaration of operator I got another error :`CLogger* operator<<(CLogger*, const char*)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type`.

                                                              ^

Comment: @drewpol Just added to the answer about that.

Comment: thank You very much for Your answers. I have explained why I am getting pointer to my class via pointer in comment above my first post.

Comment: @drewpol If you have to take the `CLogger` by pointer then you will not be able to have a pointer or built in type as the second parameter of the function.

Comment: Now I understand my mistake and I need to invent another way to achieve my goals.